# Python Selenium get value of tooltip text with javascript website

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, xpath, tooltip

I am new to Selenium. Read through many historical posts and try to retrieve tooltip text but fail...

X path (for "col_issued_shares" should be correct as it is directly copy like below screen:

[Screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R4rjC.png)

The result is SyntaxError: invalid syntax. My expected output is Issued Shares 20,428,671,958 ( as at 27 May 2022) . But when I view source , it shows toolkit text.

[Screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PPO3w.png)

[Screenshot 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpMuQ.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver import Chrome
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


s=Service(r'C:\Users\chromedriver.exe')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=s)
url='https://www.hkex.com.hk/Market-Data/Securities-Prices/Equities/Equities-Quote?sym=5&sc_lang=en'
driver.get(url)

element = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//*[@id="lhkexw-quoteequities"]/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/span")
```

Can someone help? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try xpath `//*[@id='lhkexw-quoteequities']/div[2]/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/span[2]/span`

Actually you are enclosing xpath with double quotes ("). So in xpath you should use single-quote (') for `@id=''`.

Comment: changed and run below is result.

<selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement (session="b2beaba3610734bf8684c8c0f92319d8", element="44c5736b-847d-400c-bf79-97086acd8ccb")>

Comment: How can I get this result?? Issued Shares 20,428,671,958 ( as at 27 May 2022)

Comment: @Jodie
I checked the screenshot that you have attached. As per that, your xpath should be `//span[contains(@class, 'col_issued_shares')]`

To print the text

`print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[contains(@class, 'col_issued_shares')]").text)`

Comment: You are right. Now I get result :20,428,671,958 (as at 27 May 2022), BIG THANKS!!.  
Next step , I will explore ways to search a list of securities and print out their issued shares into csv format. Will keep you posted.